# Auto adjust font-size of a div which have fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-size

I have a div with following properties

```
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #999999;
border: 1px solid #639BBE;
height: 62px;
margin-top: 13px;
width: 135px;
```

width and height of this div is fixed i cannot change them , now if i enter some big text in that div it goes outside the div , i want to so something by which i can handle this , mean if the text of this div increases it automatically decrease the font size to adjust the text . No problem if i need to add  some javascript nothing is restricted .

at the moment when i enter big text it's showing like this !

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your height is fixed. There will always be a chance where your condition meets.( Unless you plan to make text size really, and really small. which you can do via javascript

Comment: But how can i do this in javascript ?

Comment: wrap the content text in another element within your container, check it's height as percentage of container height and adjust font-size accordingly... or use css overflow to have scroll in container. Based on size of text shown..overflow likely better choice

Comment: @charlietfl i need to minimize the font-size , i cannot allow scroll

Comment: OK.. go with first suggestion then

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.HasScrollBar = function() {
//note: clientHeight= height of holder
//scrollHeight= we have content till this height
var _elm = $(this)[0];
var _hasScrollBar = false; 
if ((_elm.clientHeight < _elm.scrollHeight) || (_elm.clientWidth < _elm.scrollWidth)) {
    _hasScrollBar = true;
}
return _hasScrollBar;
}
```

use this function to find out the over flow and change the font size using jquery